# Linked Lists remove function in c++

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to finish up an assignment regarding linked lists in c++ but my remove function seems to be crashing the app every time I try to use it. I've tried a few different things but I seriously don't know what's wrong. For example if I only have one item in the list and try to remove it it crushes same goes for any other case. If anyone knows what's wrong please help :)

```
template <class T>
Error_code List<T>::retrieve(string fn, T& item)
{
    if (empty()) return underflow;

    Node<T>* temp = head;

    while (temp->entry.FlightNO.compare(fn) != 0) {
        if (temp->next == NULL)
            return not_found;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    item = temp->entry;

    return success;
}

template <class T>
Error_code List<T>::remove(T& item)
{
    Node<T>* current = head;
    Node<T>* search = new Node<T>(item);

    if (head == search) {
        head = head->next;
        return success;
    }

    else {
        Node<T>* previous = current;
        current = current->next;

        if (current->next == NULL) {
            delete current;
            return success;
        }

        while (current != search)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }

        previous->next = current->next;
        return success;
    }
}
```

This is my code, the first function is to retrieve the item and check if it actually exists, then the second is the remove which doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: Heya! you have memory leaks all over the place. Starting on `if (head == search)`. This is never going to be true since you just did `search = new Node<T>(item);` 1 line earlier. What you need to do, first, is compare the values of type `T` (not the pointers to instances of `Node<T>`) to find what to remove. Only after it is done, try to see if you can debug.

Comment: Check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Some red flags in your solution: `remove` function creates a new node (it should only delete nodes, so something is off), a pointer to a newly created node is compared with `head` immediately after; a comparison which is always false.

Comment: Also, try running the code with Address Sanitizer/Memory Sanitizer/Valgrind to get a little more useful information about crashes. Or, yes, use a debugger, it should help as well.

Comment: Memory leaks all over that code. Like `new Node<T>(item)` followed by a `return`… Who is going to deallocate that?

Answer (score 3):

Everything what was mentioned in the comments is on point. However you came here looking for an answer, so here you go:

```
template <class T>
Error_code List<T>::remove(T& item)
{
    Node<T>* current = head;
    Node<T>* search = new Node<T>(item); // <--- why?

    //if (head == search) {    //<-- always false
    //    head = head->next;
    //    return success;
    //}


    Node<T>* previous = current;
    current = current->next;

    if (current->next == NULL) {
        delete current;
        return success;
    }

    while (current != search) // <--- fails here, this is always true (you are comparing pointers, not objects)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next; // <--- because this loop is always true and you have a nullptr terminated list then this will segfault with RAV
    }

    previous->next = current->next;
    return success;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just to clarify what causes the segfault, at the "end of the loop" you eventually call

`nullptr->next;`